# Spring Cloud Gateway's RouteDefinitionRepository is getting called multiple times during startup and refresh

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to read the Gateway’s Route Definitions from an external service, which I wanted to achieve by creating a custom RouteDefinitionRepository class, so I started a small POC on RouteDefinitionRepository.

In this POC, while creating an implementation of RouteDefinitionRepository I have overridden the getRouteDefinations method and returned a Flux<RouteDefinition> from it which is statically built (so far not integrated with the external service). I marked this class as @Component and surprisingly I see the getRouteDefinations method is invoked three times.

My expectation is during startup and during refresh this method will get invoked only once.

**Here is the snippet of my custom Route Definition class.**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomRouteDefinationRepository implements RouteDefinitionRepository {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    @Override
    public Flux<RouteDefinition> getRouteDefinitions() {

        log.info("Inside getRouteDefinitions >>>");

        List<ApiRouteTO> list = new ArrayList<ApiRouteTO>();

        ApiRouteTO routeTO_1 = new ApiRouteTO();
        routeTO_1.setApiRouteId("1");
        routeTO_1.setName("route_1");
        routeTO_1.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/hello");
        try {
            routeTO_1.setPredicate(objectMapper.readValue(predicate_1, JsonNode.class));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error", ex);
        }

        list.add(routeTO_1);
        
        List<RouteDefinition> rdList = list.stream().map(this::getRd).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return Flux.fromIterable(rdList);

    }
```

Also to check whether Refresh Event is happening I created a @EventListener and its getting called once during startup and once during refresh.

```
@EventListener(RefreshRoutesEvent.class)
    public void handleEvents() {
        log.info(" $$$$$$$$$$$ Inside Refresh Event $$$$$$$$$$$");
    }
```

My main class (including the event listener)

```
@ComponentScan("com.poc.route.gw")
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class GwApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GwApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @EventListener(RefreshRoutesEvent.class)
    public void handleEvents() {
        log.info(" $$$$$$$$$$$ Inside Refresh Event $$$$$$$$$$$");
    }

}
```

Following is the log captured during startup

```
egouguh@IN-00215733 MINGW64 /c/workspace/poc/springgwpoc/gw/target (main)
$ java -jar gw-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.5)

2022-04-01 09:21:58.553  INFO 33400 --- [           main] com.poc.route.gw.GwApplication           : Starting GwApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11 on IN-00215733 with PID 33400 (C:\workspace\poc\springgwpoc\gw\target\gw-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by egouguh in C:\workspace\poc\springgwpoc\gw\target)
2022-04-01 09:21:58.564  INFO 33400 --- [           main] com.poc.route.gw.GwApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-04-01 09:22:01.692  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=1162eef5-9ddd-3db8-b935-0f1e65f3ea5e
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.396  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [ReadBody]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [XForwardedRemoteAddr]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Weight]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.397  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [CloudFoundryRouteService]
2022-04-01 09:22:08.805  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-04-01 09:22:15.618  INFO 33400 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8081
2022-04-01 09:22:21.042  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : Inside getRouteDefinitions >>>
2022-04-01 09:22:21.183  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : route route_1 has been added / refreshed
2022-04-01 09:22:21.217  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : Inside getRouteDefinitions >>>
2022-04-01 09:22:21.219  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : route route_1 has been added / refreshed
2022-04-01 09:22:21.321  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : Inside getRouteDefinitions >>>
2022-04-01 09:22:21.322  INFO 33400 --- [           main] .p.r.g.r.CustomRouteDefinationRepository : route route_1 has been added / refreshed
2022-04-01 09:22:21.324  INFO 33400 --- [           main] com.poc.route.gw.GwApplication           :  $$$$$$$$$$$ Inside Refresh Event $$$$$$$$$$$
2022-04-01 09:22:21.338  INFO 33400 --- [           main] com.poc.route.gw.GwApplication           : Started GwApplication in 26.287 seconds (JVM running for 27.906)
```

I am running it under Java 11 with Spring Boot version 2.6.5 and Spring cloud version is 2021.0.1

The code is in the following git repo and is publicly accessible:
https://github.com/gourabepsilon/springgwpoc.git

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will only get called once

Comment: Ok, its strange but can you explain why? Also is these any recommended approach to do so?